# Plugin Error on activating

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, shortcode, visual-editor

I'm building theme. but for custom post type, custom taxonomies and shortodes . I created the simple plugin. just plugin info and then functions to create CPT CT and shortcode. here is the example:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Cat Custom Plugin
Description: This is the plugin to include all custom post types, custom taonomies and shortcodes
Version: 0.1
License: GPL
Author: M.Hussy
Author URI: url
*/
include_once('inc/section-shortcodes.php');
include_once('inc/content-shortcodes.php');
include_once('inc/custom-post-tax.php');
include_once('inc/mce.php');
?>
```

Now the problem is when i activate the plugin it gives me the error:

> The plugin generated 1 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

and then the visual editor is editable... Please Help.. Thanks..

Comment: Are you using NotePad++ while writing the plug-in ? if yes, once finished don't forget to check `Encoding` and set it to `Encode in UTF-8 without BOM` instead of `Encode in UTF-8`

Comment: check for space before/after the php open/close tags. note that php files don't need a closing tag if there is no output intended after php execution.

Comment: @samuel I'm using sublime text 3. and its showing Encode in UTF-8 and Encode in UTF-8 with BOM. I set the Encode in UTF-8. no change and visual editor still not editable. :'(

Comment: @milo . I removed the closing tag. and it is not showing the error but visual editor is not editable :( ..